# Detect users sexuality based on gender and interested in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a registration form and I would like to detect in the database if user is straight, bisexual, or homosexual based on their answers. User would select I'm a man or woman. The user then gets to choose which gender they're interested in. Now the part I don't know how to do is if a user selects 'man' for both options this should show in my database under column sexuality as 'homosexual' (the same would apply if woman was chosen for both options). Then if user chooses 'man' but this time is interested in 'both' it would in the database show 'bisexual'. And finally if user chooses 'man' and for interested in selects 'woman' it would show that user is 'straight'. And of course the sexuality options would be flip flop around if the gender select was 'woman'.

I am not sure how to do that. I am not using a gem for my registration form.

```
<div class="field">I'm a <%= f.select :gender, ['man', 'woman']%> interested in <%= f.select :gender, ['woman', 'men', 'both']%> </div>
```

Comment: Isn't that something you should let the user decide?

Comment: You're missing an 'asexual' option. Also support for transgendered folk.

Comment: The user is deciding their sexuality based on the gender they're interested in.

Comment: I guess one way to do it to remove the complexity of this all is to present 'I am a [gender] that's [sexuality]. I would have to use 'gay' as a option as oppose to 'homosexual' since it wouldn't fit in with the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not commenting on the validity of what you want to do but here's a suggestion on how to do it.

This type of functionality would typically be abstracted to the controller.

Rails has a good guide for forms: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form

You will want to have your form submit to an action which will save the preferences. In the controller/action you can compare the values of the fields (gender, interested in etc.) and save the correct value. You can write code in the controller to compare the interested in value and gender value and produce sexuality which you would then save.

```
if params[:interested_in] == "both"
    sexuality = "bisexual"
else
    sexuality = (params[:gender == params[:interested_in]) ? "homosexual" : "heterosexual"
end
```